# Angler NPC rewards

Tags: terraria

There's a fishing reward at a certain quest I complete. What if I get a lot of those fishing quest items and created a lot of accounts, I then gave them one by one with each character. Do I still get those rewards like the golden fishing rod after a a certain amount of fishing quest item I gave the angler(NPC) ?

Comment: Is there anything to let you believe you wouldn't? I've never ran into an untradeable item in Terraria.. plus, rewards are random. It's not like you *have* to complete 100 questions for that special today or item

Comment: @Gnemlock they're not uniformly random. You get better rewards the more quests that character has completed.

Comment: https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Angler#Quest_rewards

Comment: @OrangeDog, being "not uniformly random" still quantifies something as being "random". Chances of functionality increase, but there's still no guarantee of the item you will or will not get, apart from the 30th reward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angler rewards based on number of quests completed has nothing to do with the items a player has. It's actually part of the character's data. So when you have something like the Golden Fishing Rod that is given out after the 30th completed quest, it is given out after that *character* completes 30 quests. Regardless of items they possess or the world they are completed in.